# How to make custom URL mandatory?

Tags: 8

I'd like to force users to customize URL. How to make the following field mandatory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path alias is a field, so you just need to alter the form and set the `#required` property on the element:

```
function module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['path']['widget'][0]['alias']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: How did you identify the FORM_ID `node_form`?

Comment: @Kwadz Implement the generic `hook_form_alter` and check the third arg (`$form_id`). Or use the webprofiler module that comes with devel, I think that tells you in the debug bar